# Can I move the road to the center of the map?

Tags: prison-architect

I would like for my delivery road to pass through the center of the map.  I have built a road but it wont connect off the map.

Can I move the road to the center of the map?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not in the current version of the alpha (16), no.  The edge of the map is a protected tile, as are all the tiles of the prebuilt road:

[image: Roads don't meet the edge]

[image: And existing roads are protected]

I tried adding a road gate to force vehicles to turn right, but this didn't help as they just patiently waited for the gate to be opened (despite my field being in dire need of riot police and the fire brigade):

[image: Gates don't help]

**However, there is a (very expensive and time consuming) workaround**.  First you need to build two offices.  In the first one, appoint a warden and have him research finance from the bureaucracy screen.  Then hire an accountant and have her research land expansion.  In total this will take about 1 in game day.

This then gives you the option to purchase land plots *on the other side* of the prebuilt road for $20,000 a piece.  This can be used to give the illusion that the road has been moved and gives you your desired road in the middle:

[image: Purchasing a new plot]

[image: The finished product]

You must remember to use road gates to allow a secure space for prisoners to cross the road, if that is your intention.

Comment: Any change you played Lin2?